# Being selective about imported variables in BASH script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have three bash scripts. w.txt, t.txt and d.txt.

w.txt:

```
#!/bin/bash

wtimes=( 8:20 9:30 10:11 )
wtimef=( 10:10 11:20 13:30 )

echo $wtimes >> d.txt
```

t.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./w.txt

echo "${wtimes[1]}"
echo "${wtimef[1]}"
```

I am trying to run t.txt so I can work with the array variables $wtimes and $wtimef in t.txt without running `echo $wtimes >> d.txt`. This is very simplyfied and there are actually many more commands in w.txt that I do not want executed from within t.txt. How can I be selective here? Can someone please help?

Comment: Is modifying the code (e.g. adding some logic) allowed?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to let the imported file know that it is imported, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

wtimes=( 8:20 9:30 10:11 )
wtimef=( 10:10 11:20 13:30 )

if [ "${imported}" = "yes" ] ; then
        exit;
fi

echo $wtimes >> d.txt
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash

imported=yes

. ./w.txt

echo "${wtimes[1]}"
echo "${wtimef[1]}"
```

But you may want to rethink your strategy here. If a common set of variables is used by different scripts, it may be a good idea to put those variables in a separate file.  For example:

vars.sh:

```
wtimes=( 8:20 9:30 10:11 )
wtimef=( 10:10 11:20 13:30 )
```

w.sh:

```
. ./vars.sh
echo $wtimes >> d.txt
```

t.sh:

```
. ./vars.sh

echo "${wtimes[1]}"
echo "${wtimef[1]}"
```